# Validar contenido de una imagen en Base64

Tags: java, base64

de que forma puedo validar que el contenido de un String de una imagen en base64 sea realmente el de una imagen y no un .exe con un formato distinto....

Comment: Hola Stevn, tu pregunta fue reportada como de "baja calidad", te sugiero agregar más información a tu pregunta, debes realizarla en base a [ask].

Answer (score -1):

no se java pero en php y javascript es mas o menos asi

```
if($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] != "image/jpg")
elseif($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] != "image/png")
elseif($_FILES['imagefile']['type'] != "image/gift")
```

Comment: en un base 64 de formato `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...` la porción data:image, será esa siempre y cuando sea imagen independiente de la extensión?? o se resuelve que es imagen por la extensión que tiene?

Comment: Esto no parece ni estar cerca de responder la pregunta. quien define el tipo? el que la envia, por lo tanto, como evitaria que le enviara un exe con otro formato y decirle que efectivamente es una imagen?

Comment: Gracias por tu interés en participar en la comunidad. Tu respuesta fue reportada como de muy "baja calidad". Lo que has escrito definitivamente no constituye una respuesta a la pregunta, lo que hace bajar la calidad del sitio, revisar [answer]. Te invito a editar tu respuesta para que refleje una solución al problema o eliminarla. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en las preguntas. Saludos!